# How to make a moving arrow?

Tags: animation

I want to create an animation where a arrow points from the red circle to the blue circle.

My standard approch would be, to start with a cube on frame 1, deform the cube to a rectangle in frame 2, than to a long line and eventually in frame 4 I have the full arrow.

Now in this approach two things are not optimal:

1. The arrow looks really bad.
2. Its hard work to do this.

Is there a shorter approach to get a more accurate looking arrow which is developing during time? I know the curve->path object, but I dont know how to explain to blender that it should develop during time (as in the image below).

[image: Example]

Comment: @gandalf3 this is basically it - but how do I get the arrow at the end (instead of simply a line)?

Comment: You could use a second curve object

Comment: @gandalf3 is it also possible that the arrow is visible in the whole animation?

Comment: Couldn't you just not animate the bevel factor?

Comment: I found a proper answer to this question here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEuWVlbXVB4

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make your arrow as a Curve, and then adding a Build Modifier to it.

[image]

It will animate along the direction of the curve (represented by the arrows in Edit mode), but you can check *Reverse* to change this. Also you can cange the start and length fields to your likes.

Comment: I added a Curve by Curve->Path but I when I try to apply the build modifier I  get the error message "cannot apply constructive modifiers on curve". Also: How can I transform a Path to an arrow? How do you get the head of the arrow?